# More than one query in 'Execute' mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my simple sp executing two queries but MySQL cant allow it,
Is it any way two execute more than one query in MySQL dynamically

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%` PROCEDURE `usp_test.test`()
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
   Rollback; 
    resignal;
  END;

start transaction;
set @dynamicquery='
select Now();
select NOW();
';
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @dynamicquery;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
commit;
END
```

Comment: execute them in separated prepared querys.

Comment: I can't,actually i passed string containing queries and execute it in sp

Comment: wy dont u split them by `;` ?

Comment: Multiquery? www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: What do you mean "MySQL doesn't allow it" you can execute 1000000 queries in MySQL within 1 transaction / query / execution / whatever

Comment: @DanFromGermany I said more than one query not allow in "Execute" statement.

Comment: @Melon I cant split because it impact big on performance.

Comment: and you need to do it inside a stored procedure?

Comment: yes because sqlexception handler not declare in simple query